# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110

Tags: deployment

We try to deploy drupal application in our production server.we face this strange error
"Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110" after deploying.we made all necessary corrections in settings.php and also give Grants to webserver to access DB in DB server. Webserver and DB server physically two different servers.

We are able to connect the DB server from web server through command line.Also no firewall enabled in both servers.any one guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you botched settings.php, this is likely a MySQL configuration issues or a general server issue.  You will probably have better luck at the ServerFault or Database Administrators SE sites.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste